# How to Remove Sidebar when get_sidebar() is not get called in page?

Tags: theme-development, sidebar

I see in my WordPress theme, there is no call of get_sidebar() in single.php etc. but sidebar comes. [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar) it is telling about customizing based on get_sidebar().

I want to use get_sidebar() to include sidebar so that I can think of customization.

Is there any default method to include sidebar from where it can come ?

Comment: Like a sidebar template? Create a file called `sidebar.php` in your theme folder. When you call `get_sidebar()` it will call the `sidebar.php` template file.

Comment: what theme exactly are you working with? have you checked the other templates such as footer.php if the sidebar is called from there?